# selection sort array run time error

Tags: c++, selection-sort

This is my first time here. I really hope anyone can help me out there. So this is my problem. I keep getting run time error #2 something about a corrupt "arr". But the program runs fine until the end.  I can't figure it out.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(){
int arr1[3];
int temp;
//INPUT NUMBERS
for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
    cin>>arr1[i];
    }
cout<<endl;
//SORT

for(int c=0;c<5;c++)
{

    for (int k=0;k<5;k++)
        {   
             if(arr1[c]<arr1[k])
            {
                temp=arr1[k];
                arr1[k]=arr1[c];
                arr1[c]=temp;
            }
        }

}
    for (int m=0; m<5; m++)
    {
        cout<<arr1[m]<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are declaring an array of size 3 and using it to store 5 elements.

Comment: Like Ned said. You should declare constants to ensure you are consistent. Something like `const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5; int arr1[ARRAY_SIZE]; ... for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr1[5];
    int temp;
//INPUT NUMBERS
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
//SORT

    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        if (arr1[c] < arr1[k]) {
        temp = arr1[k];
        arr1[k] = arr1[c];
        arr1[c] = temp;
        }
    }

    }
    for (int m = 0; m < 5; m++) {
    cout << arr1[m] << endl;
    }

}
```

It compiles properly without any errors. The mistake you had made is in declaring the size of the array. If you want to store 5 in puts, you need to declare an array of size 5. Your code might work, but a good compiler will always give out an error.

The reason being that when you declare an array, you actually create a pointer to the first element of the array. And then, some memory regions are kept for this array, depending on the size. If you try to access an element that is outside these memory regions, you may encounter a garbage value.

[Here](http://ideone.com/kz7u3C)'s your code in ideone.